# Lines for labels outside arc (Pie chart) d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3js want to add lines for outside labels of a pie chart.
here is the code. Its showing labels but I want to connect it with lines for arc.

I need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1196/) but unable to produce for my example.

JavaScript:

```js
var data = [
    {name: "A", val: 11975},  
    {name: "B", val: 5871}, 
    {name: "C", val: 8916}
];

var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
    labelr = r + 30, // radius for label anchor
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    donut = d3.layout.pie(),
    arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r * .6).outerRadius(r);

var vis = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w + 150)
    .attr("height", h);

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(donut.value(function(d) { return d.val }))
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 30) + "," + r + ")");

arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);

arcs.append("svg:text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var c = arc.centroid(d),
            x = c[0],
            y = c[1],
            // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
            h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
           (y/h * labelr) +  ")"; 
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        // are we past the center?
        return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
            "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d, i) { return d.value.toFixed(2); });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.6"></script>
<script src='http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.4.6' type='text/javascript'></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see any lines in the example script you linked

Comment: sorry I put wrong address for hyperlink here the one I want http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1196/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between your code and the code you refer is the ratio of inner and outer radius of the donut with respect to the radius. So you should make some adjustments to the static values used in the calculation to work on your chart.

The adjustments made are the following.

- Changed -75 to +45 since inner radius increased 20.
- Changed -20 to
  +30 since outer radius increased 50.

Hope this helps.

```js
var data = [
    {name: "A", val: 11975},  
    {name: "B", val: 5871}, 
    {name: "C", val: 8916}
];

var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
    labelr = r + 30, // radius for label anchor
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    donut = d3.layout.pie(),
    arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r*.6).outerRadius(r);

console.log(r * .6)
console.log(r-100)

var vis = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w + 150)
    .attr("height", h);

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(donut.value(function(d) { return d.val }))
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 30) + "," + r + ")");

arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);

arcs.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (r - 45);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (r+30);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (r - 45);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (r+30);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value.toFixed(2);  })
    .each(function(d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
    });

vis.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("refX", 3)
    .attr("refY", 3)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 3)
    .attr("cy", 3)
    .attr("r", 3);

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("class", "pointer")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        } else {
            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.6"></script>
<script src='http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.4.6' type='text/javascript'></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```